# Preprocessor #define LIBVER {'1','5'} check

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am receiving libraries with include files, where version is described like below:

```
#define MSIF_DMX_LIBVER                       {'1','5'}            //LIB version
```

Problem is that I want to make conditional compilation based on the lib version. For example there are more enums in version 1.5 than 1.4, which I would like to use.

When I tried with:

```
#if (MSIF_DMX_LIBVER == {'1','5'})
```

Compilation failed with following error message:

```
error: token "{" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
```

Is it possible to make some preprocessor condition on that case? I don't want to modify every header file I get from 3rd party.

Comment: I think [this](http://awong-cuba.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/1306cuba/core/drv_bsp/m12_nos_r2m/include/apiDMX.h) is the header you're using. I can't think of a way to use that in a preprocessor definition. I'd talk to the author about adding a more usable version macro -- but of course that won't help for existing versions. Is there another macro that's defined in 1.5 but not in 1.4?

Comment: If you require version information at compile-time, using anything other than integers is only going to cause you pain...
With regard to a solution to your problem, you could have either a script or another C program use the header and generate another .h file that contains an integer definition of the version.